# How to convert `ArrayList<String>` into a type that can be passed into a `String...` parameter

Tags: java

I have a function that returns an `ArrayList<String>`, and I need to be able to pass the result of this function into another function with a `String...` parameter. The problem is, the function that takes in the `String...` has another string already being passed in, as shown in the example below.

```java
public void printStrings(String... strings) {
    for (String str : strings) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}

public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("Hello");
    list.add("World");

    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // This is what needs to happen, but does not work
    printStrings("Additional String", getArrayList());
    //            ^ String already being passed in

}
```

This additional string should not be removed, and in the actual code the function that takes in the strings would have a lot of other strings going into it, and this function should not be changed.

Note that this is not converting an ArrayList to a String[]. That would not fix this problem.

Comment: Java does not provide a nice way to do this. You  could get the list, store it in a variable, prepend your additional string, and then call the method like `printStrings(theList.toArray(String[]::new))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a language construct that supports this exactly. You could store the `List` in a variable, add the additional String to the front, then convert to an array.

```java
var list = getArrayList();
list.add(0, "Additional String");
printStrings(list.toArray(String[]::new));
```

Comment: I would like a cleaner solution, but this will have to do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

collections cannot passed to variadic-length argument. You can pass them (including first argument in original snippet) by collection:

```java
public void printStrings(List<String> strings) {
    for (String str : strings) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}

public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("Hello");
    list.add("World");

    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> original = getArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> cloned = new ArrayList<>(original.size() + 1);
    cloned.add("Additional String");
    cloned.addAll(original);
    printStrings(cloned);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```java
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listOfStrings = getArrayList();
    listOfStrings.add("Additional String");
    
    printStrings(listOfStrings);
  }

  public static void printStrings(List<String> strings) {
    for (String str : strings) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
  }

  public static ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  
      list.add("Hello");
      list.add("World");
  
      return list;
  }
}
```

?